How to filter WFS by intersecting polygon
I'm trying to retrive data from a WFS service using a polygon for a filter.
Working URL:
https://sosgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SOS/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SOS:SpeciesObservations&outputFormat=application/json&count=10

The polygon I want to filter by: Polygon ((760130 7090468, 759931 7090075, 760594 7090169, 760130 7090468))
CRS is EPSG:3006
My attempt:
https://sosgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SOS/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SOS:SpeciesObservations&outputFormat=application/json&CQL_Filter=INTERSECTS(the_geom,Polygon ((760130 7090468, 759931 7090075, 760594 7090169, 760130 7090468)))&count=10


Illegal property name: the_geom for feature type
SOS:SpeciesObservations


Run one request with the default GML outputformat.
https://sosgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SOS/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SOS:SpeciesObservations&count=10

Have a look at one geometry
<SOS:pointLocation>
<gml:Point srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326" srsDimension="2" gml:id="SpeciesObservations.-PRCMZAB3UX-8XLUkbyq.pointLocation">
<gml:pos>65.9530037430897 19.407185428432143</gml:pos>
</gml:Point>
</SOS:pointLocation>

Edit your query to use the correct geometry name (pointLocation) and notice that the geometries are in EPSG:4326, in Lat-Lon axis order.
Try again
https://sosgeo.artdata.slu.se/geoserver/SOS/ows?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=SOS:SpeciesObservations&CQL_Filter=INTERSECTS(pointLocation,POLYGON (( 62.5089 16.2054, 62.5089 16.2056, 62.5091 16.2056, 62.5091 16.2054, 62.5089 16.2054 )))&count=10&outputFormat=application/json

You will get results
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "SpeciesObservations.Fe08MZAB3UX-8XLU_1DC",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    16.205531751639,
                    62.5089661326
                ]
            },
            "geometry_name": "pointLocation",
            "properties": {
                "occurrenceId": "urn:lsid:herbarium.emg.umu.se:observation:S*B748*2660",
                "url": null,
                "isPresentObservation": true,
                "dataProviderId": 7,
                "datasetName": "Virtual Herbarium",
                "startDate": "1941-09-29T22:00:00Z",
                "endDate": "1941-09-29T22:00:00Z",
                "modified": null,
                "decimalLatitude": 62.50897,
                "decimalLongitude": 16.20553,
                "coordinateUncertaintyInMeters": 1500,
                "locality": null,
                "municipality": "Ånge",
                "county": "Västernorrland",
                "province": "Medelpad",
                "institutionCode": null,
                "recordedBy": "T. G. Halle",
                "reportedBy": null,
                "habitat": null,
                "occurrenceRemarks": "Medelpad, Torp, Gissjön, sundet, 1-2 m djup",
                "eventRemarks": null,
                "dyntaxaTaxonId": 2660,
                "taxonCategory": "Art",
                "organismGroup": "Mossor",
                "vernacularName": "stor näckmossa",
                "scientificName": "Fontinalis antipyretica",
                "isRedlisted": false,
...


If you look at the feature schema (by making a DescribeFeatureType request) you will see that there is no attribute called the_geom, it looks like you have a choice of:
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="point" nillable="true" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType" />
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="pointLocation" nillable="true" type="gml:PointPropertyType" />

